# Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface android.app.IAlarmManager

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, gson

I've gone through many articles but none of them answered my case.
I am trying to get an `ArrayList` of my custom class type `AnAlarm` from already stored `SharedPreferences`. I've stored the ArrayList `alarms` in the `SharedPreferences` as a `Json String` and now I am trying to get this **ArrayList** by using the following code:

```
            String alarms_temp_string=preferences.getString("alarms",null);
            if(alarms_temp_string==null){
               alarms =new ArrayList<AnAlarm>();
               }

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type type=new TypeToken<ArrayList<AnAlarm>> (){}.getType();
            ArrayList<AnAlarm> alarms=gson.fromJson(alarms_temp_string,type);
            adapter=new RecyclerViewAdapter(alarms);
```

But I am getting the following exception:

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface android.app.IAlarmManager. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
```

on this line of code:

```
ArrayList<AnAlarm> alarms=gson.fromJson(alarms_temp_string,type);
```

When I comment the above line, the remaining program runs smoothly.

Following is my custom class `AnAlarm` code:

```
public class AnAlarm {

    private Calendar calendar;

    public AnAlarm(){}

    public AnAlarm(Calendar calendar) {

        this.calendar = calendar;

    }

    public Calendar getCalendar() {
        return calendar;
    }

    public void setCalendar(Calendar calendar) {
        this.calendar = calendar;
    }


}
```

In this class there is also a **no-Arguments constructors** as well as all `getters` and `setters` are present. Why am I getting this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use `Gson` simply if you have instances of a third class declared inside your custom class.

In your case you have instance of `Calendar` inside your class `AnAlarm`. Remove it and try again!

If you are forced to use it anyway, please make use of **instance creator** for your class. See this article:
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-advanced-custom-instance-creator

Comment: If we want to ignore any field from serialising, we can use transient modifier for that field, instead of removing the field.